# Why Laravel Redis::throttle is so slow when could not obtain lock?

Tags: laravel, redis, throttling

I'm trying to throttle heavy operations like said in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#rate-limiting). When operation is allowed - it fires blazing fast.

But when operation meets throttle limit - it waits ~3 seconds before firing on throttle callback. Here is the code:

```
Artisan::command('temp', function () {
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::debug("Start temp");
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::throttle("test123")
        ->allow(1)
        ->every(5)
        ->then(function () {
            Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::debug("Logged immediately when allowed");
        }, function () {
            Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::debug("Logged after ~3 seconds on throttle");
        });

        Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::debug("Logged immediately or after ~3 seconds depending on above");
});
```

I expected `on throttle` callback fires immediately too. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was facing the same issue, I figured out why it takes so long - 
looking at `Illuminate\Redis\Limiters\DurationLimiterBuilder` we see:

```
/**
 * The amount of time to block until a lock is available.
 *
 * @var int
 */
public $timeout = 3;
```

...

```
/**
 * Set the amount of time to block until a lock is available.
 *
 * @param  int  $timeout
 * @return $this
 */
public function block($timeout)
{
    $this->timeout = $timeout;

    return $this;
}
```

So theoretically you just need to add `->block(1)` or if you are using jobs and you requeue them with a delay, you could use 0 as well.

(Actually I had to clear the cache and did a `composer dump-autoload` to make it work)

Besides, if you use the `redis-cli monitor`command you see what's happening in the cache, nice for debugging.

**EDIT:**
*After a while I changed to `Redis::funnel`, you might have a look into that as well*